# NLTK words vs word_tokenize

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, tokenize, corpus

I'm exploring some of NLTK's corpora and came across the following behaviour: **word_tokenize() and words produce different sets of words()**.

Here is an example using webtext:

```
from nltk.corpus import webtext
```

When I run the following,

```
len(set(word_tokenize(webtext.raw('wine.txt'))))
```

I get: 3488

When I run the following,

```
len(set(webtext.words('wine.txt')))
```

I get: 3414

All I can find in the documentation is that word_tokenize is a list of punctuation and words. But it also says words is a list of punctuation and words. I'm wondering, what's going on here? Why are they different?

I've already tried looking at the set differences.

```
U = set(word_tokenize(webtext.raw('wine.txt')))
V = set(webtext.words('wine.txt'))

tok_not_in_words = U.difference(V) # in tokenize but not in words
words_not_in_tok = V.difference(U) # in words but not in tokenize
```

All I can see is that word_tokenize contains hyphenated words and words splits the hyphenated words.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Very good question!! I'll get to the answer when I'm free later if no one else has given an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First lets take a look at the count the tokens from both approach and see the `most_common` words:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize
>>> from nltk.corpus import webtext

>>> counts_from_wordtok = Counter(word_tokenize(webtext.raw('wine.txt')))
>>> counts_from_wordtok.most_common(10)
[(u'.', 2824), (u',', 1550), (u'a', 821), (u'and', 786), (u'the', 706), (u'***', 608), (u'-', 518), (u'of', 482), (u'but', 474), (u'I', 390)]

>>> counts_from_words = Counter(webtext.words('wine.txt'))
>>> counts_from_words.most_common(10)
[(u'.', 2772), (u',', 1536), (u'-', 832), (u'a', 821), (u'and', 787), (u'the', 706), (u'***', 498), (u'of', 482), (u'but', 474), (u'I', 392)]


>>> len(word_tokenize(webtext.raw('wine.txt')))
31140
>>> len(webtext.words('wine.txt'))
31350
```

## Something smells fishy...

Lets take a closer look of how `webtext` interface comes about, it uses the `LazyCorpusLoader` at [https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/corpus/**init**.py#L235](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/corpus/__init__.py#L235)

```
webtext = LazyCorpusLoader(
    'webtext', PlaintextCorpusReader, r'(?!README|\.).*\.txt', encoding='ISO-8859-2')
```

If we look at how `PlaintextCorpusReader` is loading the corpus and tokenizing https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/corpus/reader/plaintext.py#L41

```
class PlaintextCorpusReader(CorpusReader):
    CorpusView = StreamBackedCorpusView

    def __init__(self, root, fileids,
                 word_tokenizer=WordPunctTokenizer(),
                 sent_tokenizer=nltk.data.LazyLoader(
                     'tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle'),
                 para_block_reader=read_blankline_block,
                 encoding='utf8'):
```

## Ah ha! It's using the `WordPunctTokenizer` instead of the default modified `TreebankTokenizer`

The `WordPunctTokenizer` is a simplistic tokenizer found at https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tokenize/regexp.py#L171

The `word_tokenize()` function is a modified `TreebankTokenizer` unique to NLTK [https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tokenize/**init**.py#L97](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py#L97)

If we look at what's `webtext.words()` calling, we follow https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/corpus/reader/plaintext.py#L81

```
def words(self, fileids=None):
    """
    :return: the given file(s) as a list of words
        and punctuation symbols.
    :rtype: list(str)
    """
    return concat([self.CorpusView(path, self._read_word_block, encoding=enc)
                   for (path, enc, fileid)
                   in self.abspaths(fileids, True, True)])
```

to reach `_read_word_block()` at https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/corpus/reader/plaintext.py#L119 :

```
def _read_word_block(self, stream):
    words = []
    for i in range(20): # Read 20 lines at a time.
        words.extend(self._word_tokenizer.tokenize(stream.readline()))
    return words
```

It's reading the file line by line!

### So if we load the `webtext` corpus and use the `WordPunctTokenizer` we get the same number:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import webtext
>>> from nltk.tokenize import WordPunctTokenizer
>>> wpt = WordPunctTokenizer()
>>> len(wpt.tokenize(webtext.raw('wine.txt')))
31350
>>> len(webtext.words('wine.txt'))
31350
```

---

## More mysteries

You can also create a new `webtext` corpus object by specifying the tokenizer object e.g.

```
>>> from nltk.tokenize import _treebank_word_tokenizer
>>> from nltk.corpus import LazyCorpusLoader, PlaintextCorpusReader
>>> from nltk.corpus import webtext

# LazyCorpusLoader expects a tokenizer object,
# but word_tokenize() is a function, so we have to 
# import the tokenizer object that word_tokenize wraps around
>>> webtext2 = LazyCorpusLoader('webtext', PlaintextCorpusReader, r'(?!README|\.).*\.txt', encoding='ISO-8859-2', word_tokenizer=_treebank_word_tokenizer)

>>> len(webtext2.words('wine.txt'))
28385

>>> len(word_tokenize(webtext2.raw('wine.txt')))
31140


>>> list(webtext2.words('wine.txt'))[:100]
[u'Lovely', u'delicate', u',', u'fragrant', u'Rhone', u'wine.', u'Polished', u'leather', u'and', u'strawberries.', u'Perhaps', u'a', u'bit', u'dilute', u',', u'but', u'good', u'for', u'drinking', u'now.', u'***', u'Liquorice', u',', u'cherry', u'fruit.', u'Simple', u'and', u'coarse', u'at', u'the', u'finish.', u'**', u'Thin', u'and', u'completely', u'uninspiring.', u'*', u'Rough.', u'No', u'Stars', u'Big', u',', u'fat', u',', u'textured', u'Chardonnay', u'-', u'nuts', u'and', u'butterscotch.', u'A', u'slightly', u'odd', u'metallic/cardboard', u'finish', u',', u'but', u'probably', u'***', u'A', u'blind', u'tasting', u',', u'other', u'than', u'the', u'fizz', u',', u'which', u'included', u'five', u'vintages', u'of', u'Cote', u'Rotie', u'Brune', u'et', u'Blonde', u'from', u'Guigal', u'.', u'Surprisingly', u'young', u'feeling', u'and', u'drinking', u'well', u',', u'but', u'without', u'any', u'great', u'complexity.', u'A', u'good', u'***', u'Charming', u',', u'violet-fragranced', u'nose.']

>>> word_tokenize(webtext2.raw('wine.txt'))[:100]
[u'Lovely', u'delicate', u',', u'fragrant', u'Rhone', u'wine', u'.', u'Polished', u'leather', u'and', u'strawberries', u'.', u'Perhaps', u'a', u'bit', u'dilute', u',', u'but', u'good', u'for', u'drinking', u'now', u'.', u'***', u'Liquorice', u',', u'cherry', u'fruit', u'.', u'Simple', u'and', u'coarse', u'at', u'the', u'finish', u'.', u'**', u'Thin', u'and', u'completely', u'uninspiring', u'.', u'*', u'Rough', u'.', u'No', u'Stars', u'Big', u',', u'fat', u',', u'textured', u'Chardonnay', u'-', u'nuts', u'and', u'butterscotch', u'.', u'A', u'slightly', u'odd', u'metallic/cardboard', u'finish', u',', u'but', u'probably', u'***', u'A', u'blind', u'tasting', u',', u'other', u'than', u'the', u'fizz', u',', u'which', u'included', u'five', u'vintages', u'of', u'Cote', u'Rotie', u'Brune', u'et', u'Blonde', u'from', u'Guigal', u'.', u'Surprisingly', u'young', u'feeling', u'and', u'drinking', u'well', u',', u'but', u'without', u'any', u'great']
```

That's because `word_tokenize` does a `sent_tokenize` before actually tokenizing sentences into words: [https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tokenize/**init**.py#L113](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py#L113)

But the `PlaintextCorpusReader. _read_word_block()` doesn't do `sent_tokenize` beforehand, https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/corpus/reader/plaintext.py#L119

Let's do a recount with sentence tokenization first:

```
>>> len(word_tokenize(webtext2.raw('wine.txt')))
31140

>>> sum(len(tokenized_sent) for tokenized_sent in webtext2.sents('wine.txt'))
31140
```

Note: The `sent_tokenizer` of `PlaintextCorpusReader` uses the `sent_tokenizer=nltk.data.LazyLoader('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')` which is the same object shared with the `nltk.sent_tokenize()` function.

## Voila!

**Why is it that `words()` don't do sentence tokenization first?**

I think it's because it was originally using the `WordPunctTokenizer` that doesn't need the string to be sentence tokenized first, whereas the `TreebankWordTokenizer` requires the string to be tokenized first.

**Why is it that in the age of "deep learning" and "machine learning", we are still using regex based tokenizers and everything else in NLP are largely based on these tokens?**

I have no ideas... But there are alternatives, e.g. http://gmb.let.rug.nl/elephant/about.php